# Not all users are retrieved with Microsoft.Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I need to retrieved from Azure Active Directory all members (users) of a group, including those within nested groups. Here is my code:

```
        ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

        IGroupTransitiveMembersCollectionWithReferencesPage members = await graphServiceClient.Groups["{myGroupId"]  
            .TransitiveMembers
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

        List<string> repEmails = members.OfType<User>().Select(member => $"{member.DisplayName} <{member.Mail}>").ToList();
```

This does retrieve the data, but today I realized that some of the users are missing in my list of results. Am I missing something, or is there any limitations on how many users can be retrieved?

P.S. I found the following elsewhere in Stack Overflow:

> Please note that it might not return all the users if there are too
> many. In that case you will get uri with nextLink to get next batch of
> results.

How can this be done?

Comment: The docs are usually the best place to get this stuff... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Graph requests, which return a collection (like users, groups, etc.) are put into an collection object that is (within C#) named with *Page* at the end of the class name.

So you only get the first n element back. You can set the desired value through the `$top` query parameter (or in C# with `.Top(x)`). But be aware that the maximum allowed value can vary depending on the kind of collection you're going to ask. Most of them have a maximum value of 999, but a few have lower values (If you pick a too high number you get back an error message containing the maximum allowed value).

The retrieved page object has a property `NextPageRequest` which will be not null, if further data is available and you can get it by calling it:

```
var moreMembers = await members.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
```

You can do this in a while loop, till the property `NextPageRequest` is `null` to get a list of all members.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You can also use a [`PageIterator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp).

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: Yes, you're right. Just forgot about it.